# Objectdraw Java: WindowController.class Source File Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently opened up a project that I hadn't worked on in a while. I'm using the program Eclipse, programming with Java. I go to run my project, to see where I am/left off. I get an error, and I'm like "oh yeah, I forgot to re-import Objectdraw." so I did that, as I had been doing before and I expected it to work fine. but then I got another error: WindowController.class cannot find a source folder. I don't know why, nor can I figure out how to solve this. My guess is that when I'm attaching the source, I don't know what I'm looking at. I only really started programming in June (this is my only project right now, and I just said that I had not worked on it in awhile, so I'm a real noob here) and I just need some help. What would be the source file that I'm looking for? Where would it be? If I for some reason don't have it, can I download it from somewhere?

This is what I'm seeing:

First, a heading that says "Source not found", with text that reads "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file WindowController.class.
You can change the source attachment by clicking Changed Attached Source below:
Then a "Change Attached Source" button.
Then I see this:

```
    // Compiled from WindowController.java (version 1.1 : 45.3, super bit)
public class objectdraw.WindowController extends objectdraw.Controller {

  // Field descriptor #6 Lobjectdraw/DrawingCanvas;
  protected objectdraw.DrawingCanvas canvas;

  // Method descriptor #8 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public WindowController();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial objectdraw.Controller() [10]
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  new objectdraw.JDrawingCanvas [12]
     8  dup
     9  invokespecial objectdraw.JDrawingCanvas() [14]
    12  putfield objectdraw.WindowController.canvas : objectdraw.DrawingCanvas [15]
    15  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 42]
        [pc: 4, line: 47]
        [pc: 15, line: 42]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 16] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController

  // Method descriptor #8 ()V
  // Stack: 4, Locals: 2
  protected void helpinit();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial objectdraw.Controller.setup() : void [22]
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  invokevirtual javax.swing.JApplet.getContentPane() : java.awt.Container [25]
     8  aload_0 [this]
     9  getfield objectdraw.WindowController.canvas : objectdraw.DrawingCanvas [15]
    12  checkcast java.awt.Component [31]
    15  ldc <String "Center"> [33]
    17  invokevirtual java.awt.Container.add(java.awt.Component, java.lang.Object) : void [35]
    20  aload_0 [this]
    21  invokevirtual java.awt.Container.validate() : void [41]
    24  aload_0 [this]
    25  getfield objectdraw.WindowController.canvas : objectdraw.DrawingCanvas [15]
    28  invokeinterface objectdraw.DrawingCanvas.repaint() : void [44] [nargs: 1]
    33  goto 39
    36  invokestatic java.lang.Thread.yield() : void [49]
    39  aload_0 [this]
    40  getfield objectdraw.WindowController.canvas : objectdraw.DrawingCanvas [15]
    43  invokeinterface objectdraw.DrawingCanvas.getWidth() : int [54] [nargs: 1]
    48  ifeq 36
    51  aload_0 [this]
    52  invokevirtual objectdraw.WindowController.begin() : void [58]
    55  aload_0 [this]
    56  invokevirtual java.awt.Container.validate() : void [41]
    59  new objectdraw.WindowControllerListener [61]
    62  dup
    63  aload_0 [this]
    64  aload_0 [this]
    65  getfield objectdraw.WindowController.canvas : objectdraw.DrawingCanvas [15]
    68  invokespecial objectdraw.WindowControllerListener(objectdraw.WindowController, objectdraw.DrawingCanvas) [63]
    71  astore_1 [listener]
    72  aload_0 [this]
    73  getfield objectdraw.WindowController.canvas : objectdraw.DrawingCanvas [15]
    76  aload_1 [listener]
    77  invokeinterface objectdraw.DrawingCanvas.addMouseListener(java.awt.event.MouseListener) : void [66] [nargs: 2]
    82  aload_0 [this]
    83  getfield objectdraw.WindowController.canvas : objectdraw.DrawingCanvas [15]
    86  aload_1 [listener]
    87  invokeinterface objectdraw.DrawingCanvas.addMouseMotionListener(java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener) : void [70] [nargs: 2]
    92  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 54]
        [pc: 4, line: 56]
        [pc: 20, line: 61]
        [pc: 24, line: 62]
        [pc: 33, line: 63]
        [pc: 36, line: 64]
        [pc: 39, line: 63]
        [pc: 51, line: 70]
        [pc: 55, line: 71]
        [pc: 59, line: 73]
        [pc: 64, line: 74]
        [pc: 68, line: 73]
        [pc: 72, line: 76]
        [pc: 82, line: 77]
        [pc: 92, line: 78]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 93] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController
        [pc: 72, pc: 93] local: listener index: 1 type: objectdraw.WindowControllerListener

  // Method descriptor #8 ()V
  // Stack: 0, Locals: 1
  public void begin();
    0  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 85]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController

  // Method descriptor #77 (Lobjectdraw/Location;)V
  // Stack: 0, Locals: 2
  public void onMouseClick(objectdraw.Location point);
    0  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 93]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: point index: 1 type: objectdraw.Location

  // Method descriptor #77 (Lobjectdraw/Location;)V
  // Stack: 0, Locals: 2
  public void onMousePress(objectdraw.Location point);
    0  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 101]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: point index: 1 type: objectdraw.Location

  // Method descriptor #77 (Lobjectdraw/Location;)V
  // Stack: 0, Locals: 2
  public void onMouseRelease(objectdraw.Location point);
    0  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 109]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: point index: 1 type: objectdraw.Location

  // Method descriptor #77 (Lobjectdraw/Location;)V
  // Stack: 0, Locals: 2
  public void onMouseEnter(objectdraw.Location point);
    0  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 117]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: point index: 1 type: objectdraw.Location

  // Method descriptor #77 (Lobjectdraw/Location;)V
  // Stack: 0, Locals: 2
  public void onMouseExit(objectdraw.Location point);
    0  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 125]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: point index: 1 type: objectdraw.Location

  // Method descriptor #77 (Lobjectdraw/Location;)V
  // Stack: 0, Locals: 2
  public void onMouseDrag(objectdraw.Location point);
    0  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 136]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: point index: 1 type: objectdraw.Location

  // Method descriptor #77 (Lobjectdraw/Location;)V
  // Stack: 0, Locals: 2
  public void onMouseMove(objectdraw.Location point);
    0  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 145]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: objectdraw.WindowController
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: point index: 1 type: objectdraw.Location
}
```

Comment: I am very confused. What is that you've posted above? It's not Java. What does your original source code look like?

Comment: Idk. In Eclipse, it's what shows on the "WindowController.class" tab (along with the Changed Attached Source" button) in place of the actual code that was once there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  
Idk. In Eclipse, it's what shows on the "WindowController.class" tab (along with the Changed Attached Source" button) in place of the actual code that was once there.